# How can I create Todoist tasks with Siri?

Tags: ios, siri, reminders, todoist

I recently started using [Todoist](https://todoist.com) as the primary reminder/task management app on my iPhone. However, one feature I miss from Apple's native Reminders app is being able to create reminders using Siri commands. (ie: "*Remind me to buy groceries tomorrow*")

**Is it possible to create Todoist reminders using Siri? Or is Siri only able to interact with Apple's native Reminders app?**

[image: Apple reminders with Siri]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use Siri with this App?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/297352/can-i-use-siri-with-this-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**As of iOS 11, [it is now possible to create and view Todoist tasks with Siri](https://support.todoist.com/hc/en-us/articles/207221555-Using-Siri-with-Todoist)**.

---

> ## [Using Siri with Todoist](https://support.todoist.com/hc/en-us/articles/207221555-Using-Siri-with-Todoist)
>
> #### Add tasks using Siri
>
> To add tasks using Siri, simply call up Siri and use natural language
>   to add tasks. You can use a few types of sentences to ensure that Siri
>   understands what you want to do:
>
> - *Add [task name] in Todoist*
> - *Add a task named [task name] in Todoist*
> - *Remind me to [task name] in Todoist*
>
> You can also add a due date and time and/or a project to any task
>   using voice commands:
>
> - *Add [task name] [due date and time] in Todoist*
> - *Add [task name] to my [project name] list in Todoist*
>
> ...
>
> #### View tasks using Siri
>
> Easily ask Siri to pull up a list of tasks by date or project, or
>   both. Here are a few examples of voice commands you can use:
>
> - *Show me all the tasks for today in Todoist*
> - *Show me all the tasks for the next 7 days in Todoist*
> - *Show me all the tasks for today between 10am and 12am in Todoist*
> - *Show me the shopping list in Todoist*
>
> <sub>**Source**: [Todoist FAQ - Using Siri with Todoist](https://support.todoist.com/hc/en-us/articles/207221555-Using-Siri-with-Todoist)</sub>

---

#### Further reading

- [FAQ: Using Siri with Todoist](https://support.todoist.com/hc/en-us/articles/207221555-Using-Siri-with-Todoist)
- [Blog: “Hey Siri, add a task to my Todoist”](https://blog.todoist.com/2017/09/19/todoist-ios11-siri-integration/)

Answer (score 2):

For now this feature is only available for Reminders.

In iOS 11 it's possible for todo list apps to use Siri. So you need to wait for iOS 11 and for the developer of Todoist to update it's app to add support for Siri.

> SiriKit gives developers the ability to integrate Siri into their
>   apps, and with iOS 11 it expands to support more categories, including
>   **to-do lists**, notes and reminders; banking for account transfers and
>   balances; and apps that display QR codes.

[*Source: look for SiriKit*](https://www.apple.com/newsroom/2017/06/ios-11-brings-new-features-to-iphone-and-ipad-this-fall/)

Comment: You should include the relevant quote from the linked source in your answer. "***SiriKit gives developers the ability to integrate Siri into their apps, and with iOS 11 it expands to support more categories, including to-do lists,** notes and reminders; banking for account transfers and balances; and apps that display QR codes.*"