# Can I use Siri with these apps?

Tags: ios, siri, third-party

Could YouTube, Todoist, myEmail (fill in name app your looking for) be controlled/used with Siri?

Could a third party iOS app be controlled by Siri?

Comment: There's a general rule. If apple made it, it's probably integrated with Siri. For others... don't hold your breath.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apple is opening up Siri for third party app developers. It's rolling out slowly in which areas Siri could be used. This to ensure the quality. Every iOS major release Apple adds categories where Siri could be used by third party apps.

### Siri works in these categories

**iOS 11:**

- To-do lists
- Notes
- Reminders
- Banking for account transfers and balances
- Apps that display QR codes.

**iOS 10:**

- Audio or video calling
- Messaging
- Payments
- Searching photos
- Workouts
- Ride booking

### Recognising

You can recognise which apps support Siri by looking for the Siri icon in the App Store.

[image: App Store - WhatsApp - Siri]

Comment: See this to answer your question for some of those apps specifically: https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi0-qew-4rWAhXDEpQKHd-4B74QtwIIKDAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D2P4SMiNEG-g&usg=AFQjCNFxhaotIPY98mkivZp2n2KO5qS-wg