# How can I ask Siri to play the first video of a YouTube search?

Tags: iphone, ios, siri

YouTube's search bar is pretty good at finding the most relevant video for a popular search. Like, if I search for "dog of wisdom" the first video is the one I want to see, so I had the thought the other day wouldn't it be nice to be able to ask Siri "play the first YouTube video with search 'dog of wisdom'" and have it play [the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D-UmfqFjpl0) immediately. There are no doubt a lot of searches like this, i.e., where the first video of the search term is expected to be the one you want, so that you don't even have to scroll around to find it. Is this something that could be done?

Comment: No. And see this Q&A on how Siri works with third party apps: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/297352/can-i-use-siri-with-these-apps

Comment: @pjc90, yes, but how is it then that I can play a YouTube video and close the screen (black) while still listening to the music, namely on my iPhone. Is that just a glitch "feature"?