# How do I determine what Siri commands an app supports?

Tags: ios, siri

When an app supports Siri commands natively, how can I figure out what commands they support?

Note that this is asking specifically about app developer-defined commands built into the app. This is not asking about Siri Shortcuts in Settings, Siri Shortcuts you can define to an aspect of an app, nor a Siri command you can bind to a Shortcut in Shortcuts.app

Some apps have static built-in commands, for example, if you view [Overcast’s App Store page](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/overcast/id888422857?mt=8) and scroll down to the bottom, you’ll see it “Supports Siri and Family Sharing”. That Siri support badge is stating it supports Siri commands external to the app. “Hey Siri, play The Talk Show on Overcast”

How can I find out what Siri commands are natively supported by an app?

Comment: Related to, but expanding on [Can I use Siri with these apps?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/297352/1346)

Answer (score 3):

Invoke Siri, but don't ask her a question; instead, tap on the waveform so that she 
stops listening and shows you suggested questions. 
Next, scroll down to the app you're interested in and tap on it to see possible voice commands.

Comment: Note that if you are using "Type to Siri" (found in the Accessibility settings), no waveform will appear. There is a question mark next to the text input field that you can tap instead.

Comment: This doesn’t appear to show an exhaustive list of installed third party apps.

Comment: To quote from [Apple's Developer documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/registering_custom_vocabulary_with_sirikit/global_vocabulary_reference/intent_phrases), `Apps are expected to provide some example phrases. Siri displays your app's sample phrases in Siri Guide so that users can access them directly from the Siri interface.` Whether developers actually follow this instruction and whether they actually list _all possible_ commands (or whether that's desirable, at all), is nearly impossible to answer, I'm afraid.

Comment: This didn’t work for me on iOS 16.5.1 (c) today.

Answer (score 2):

I've found that adding actions for an App in Shortcuts is now the best way to see all the commands the app supports.

Create a new shortcut -> Add Action -> App tab at the top -> select an app

Here's the options for Overcast:

[image: View of Overcast Shortcut Action Types]

Comment: Useful for many apps, but not all

Answer (score 0):

"Hey Siri, What can you do?" also shows the list of apps as mentioned by the other answer.